# Data Validation (dropdown) and Vlookup for google script

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a list of products and their ids in a sheet.

On the main sheet, I have a column of which accepts id as input. I need to create a dropdown for this column such that product name is displayed in the dropdown, but on selecting the option it set the value to id. I can't create another column as I need to send the entire data using API.

Any way for that user to see the product name in the dropdown, but give the sheet the product id?

Comment: Hey there, I am not sure I completely understand what is it that you want to achieve. Would you mind sharing a copy of your sheet? And provide more details in order for us to help you? @swapnilindahood

Comment: I can tell you the solution I found out. You can check it below

Answer (score 0):

I created a data validation to create the dropdown. After that, I ran a script which lookups over the value corresponding to the dropdown value. In the script, I created the vlookup function.

```
    function vlookup(sheet, column, index, value) {
    
      var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
      var data=sheet.getRange(1,column,lastRow,column+index).getValues();
    
      for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
        if (data[i][0]==value){
          return data[i][index];
        }
      }
    }
```

I called this function in a for loop for the "i" < loop length = last row count.
Here sheet is sheet object, column equal to column number to lookup value in, index is the index of the column from which value needs to get and value is set by `var value = sheet.getRange(row set by "i" in loop, fixed column with dropdown).getValue`

The values will be replaced in the sheet.